# Scrolling to bottom of div after Handlebars.js compile + jQuery append

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, handlebars.js, race-condition

So I'm trying to make the div scroll to the very bottom after loading things via jQuery.getJSON(...). I'm using Handlebars.js to compile a template, then append the content, then I want to scroll.

The problem is that about 5% of the time it doesn't actually scroll to the bottom. Is there someway to use a callback to ensure that it always scrolls all the way, no matter what?

```
$.getJSON('/api/messageGet/' + userId, function(json) {     
    $.each(json, function(i, item) {
        var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#message-template").html());
        $('#message-container').prepend(theTemplate(item));     
    }); 
    $('#message-container').scrollTop($('#message-container')[0].scrollHeight);     
});
```

Comment: try to delay the scroll using `setTimeout`. use 100ms.

Comment: That still seems like sort of a hack. Is there any other possible way?

Comment: I agree, it's a hack. But without knowing the content of your template generated HTML, it can contain anything. If the browser "takes a while" to calculate the new page height, you can't do anything about it. (You could tap on to resize events but that might cause other issues)

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Thanks for the follow up.